# Kotlin - Is it possible to return a variable from a higher order function?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have a Kotlin function from a separate library that takes a function as a parameter and gets the variable I need from the callback:

```
object Session {
    fun get(callback: (accessToken: String?) -> Unit): Boolean {
        SomeOtherClass(callback).get()
        return true
     }
}
```

Then to call it from another class I make the call (in java):

```
public String getToken() {
     Session.INSTANCE.get((accessToken) -> {
          // I want the method getToken() to be able to 'return accessToken;' 
          // but this call back returns Unit and the get method itself returns Boolean
     });
}
```

Is there a way to return the variable accessToken from getToken() directly, or at least the equivalent value? Session.get is async so creating a "global" variable returns null because the value hasn't been assigned yet. This is one thing I have tried:

```
public String getToken() {
     String temp;
     Session.INSTANCE.get((accessToken) -> {
          temp = accessToken;
     });
     return temp;
}
```

Relatively new to functional programming so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the call to get the access token is async then you can't just grab right away. This is because the code inside the `get` call is running on another thread while your code keeps going. It would look like this:

```
public String getToken() {
     String temp;                                 // 1. you make a variable
     Session.INSTANCE.get((accessToken) -> {      // 2. get call starts processing
          temp = accessToken;                     
     });
     return temp;                                 // 3. now you return your uninitialized variable
}
```

and then after your function ends the token callback happens, but its to late, you already returned nothing. If you run it in a debugger with a break point on each line and keep running you will see the order that the code is executed and it may make more sense.

Your best bet is to just handle what you need in the callback rather than returning it in `getToken()`...

Not sure if you wanted an answer in kotlin or java but your code may look something like this in kotlin:

```
Session.get { token ->
    onToken(token)
}
```

where `onToken` handles whatever code you needed the token for

```
fun onToken(token: String) {
    // do whatever code you would've executed after getToken() here
}
```

Hope I explained that alright.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a callback's eventual result from the method that calls it without blocking the thread that made the call. The reason callbacks exist is so you won't block the thread that's making the call. On Android, your app will crash with an Application Not Responding message if you block the main thread for a few seconds.

If you use Kotlin, you can wrap library callbacks using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to make them coroutine-compatible. Coroutine suspend functions do allow you to return delayed results.