# Why doesn't this function give me a true result?

Tags: android, parsing, kotlin

I'm doing a duplicate registration check on this page. When the function is running, I can see how many entries are from the same record. I saw this with println. but I cannot get this number with this function. the number returns zero. If I think it is my default value.
How can I solve this problem, can you help me?

```
open class Mukerrermi(var english: String,var turkce:String,var context: Context){

        var sonuc:Int=0

         fun kontrolEt(): Int {


                val parsUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser().email

                println("Mük "+parsUser.toString())

                val query= ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Kelimeler")
                query.whereEqualTo("User",parsUser.toString())
                val query1= ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Kelimeler")

                query.whereContains("Eng",english)
                query1.whereContains("Turk",turkce)

                val querys=ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>()
                querys.add(query)
                querys.add(query1)

                val mainQuery = ParseQuery.or<ParseObject>(querys)
                mainQuery.findInBackground { objects, e ->



                        if (e != null) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, e.localizedMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            sonuc= objects.size

                        } else {

                            sonuc= objects.size
                            println("Bulunan "+sonuc.toString())


                        }


                    }


                    println("Bulunan kayıtlar "+sonuc.toString())

                        return sonuc
```

Comment: See my answer here. You can't immediately return the value that you are going to get in the future from a callback. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992697/kotlin-is-it-possible-to-return-a-variable-from-a-higher-order-function/59994509#59994509

Comment: i use find function and run  true. Not use findinbackground func